# get next element in n-dimensional array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I was given an interview question that I just could not solve. I feel like the solution was recursive, but even then I couldn't sort through the logic. The question was as follows

Given nested arrays, write an enumerator class such that next() returns the elements in sequential order, e.g.:

So if the input is: [1,[4,3],6,[5,[1,0]]] 
The output is : 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 0

I was supposed to do it in Objective-C and my (bad solution) was

```
- (void) getNext(NSArray *) array {

  while(!array.isEmpty)
    getNext(array objectAtIndex(first);
}

NSLog(@"object is %@", [array objectAtIndex[0]]);
```

Anyone have any ideas? I would also accept a non-objective-C answer just to see the logic

Comment: I would use a stack whose elements keep track of the current positions in the currently "open" arrays; the top of the stack is the current array.  Every time the next element turns out to be a fresh array, you push an element containing a reference to it and the index (initially 0) onto this stack; every time you hit the end of the current array, you pop the stack and re-attempt the read in the "parent" array.  Otherwise, just grab the current element in the current array, and increment its index.

Comment: As a minimum, you need to check whether each item in the array is a *number* or a *subarray*. That can be done with `isKindOfClass` or `isMemberOfClass`. (I can never remember which one to use.) And then you get into the whole *class cluster* foo bar, which is probably what the interviewer was testing you on.

Comment: I think, that the problem is that that function doesn't get from which element it should return next element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a `NSArray` category.

```
@interface NSArray(EXT)
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *index;
- (NSNumber *)next;
@end

static void *aIndex = &aIndex;
@implementation NSArray (EXT)
    - (NSNumber *)index {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, aIndex);
}

- (void)setIndex:(NSNumber *)index {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, aIndex, index, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (NSNumber *)next {
    if(self.index.integerValue == self.count) {
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        id nextObj = [self objectAtIndex:self.index.integerValue];
        if([nextObj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            self.index = @(self.index.integerValue+1);
            return nextObj;
        }
        else {
            id childNext = [(NSArray *)nextObj next];
            if(childNext == nil) {
                self.index = @(self.index.integerValue+1);
                return [self next];
            }
            else {
                return childNext;
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

and you can use this like as below:

```
NSArray *input = @[@1, @[@4, @3], @6, @[@5, @[@1, @0]]];

NSNumber *next = [input next];
while (next != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", next);
    next = [input next];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem is

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *finalArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *input = @[@1, @[@4, @3], @6, @[@5, @[@1, @0]]];
    _finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self arrayToString:input];

    NSLog(@"Final array %@", [self.finalArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
}


- (void)arrayToString: (NSArray *) array {
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        [self recurseValue:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }


}


- (void)recurseValue:(id)value {
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        [self.finalArray addObject:value];
    } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (int i = 0; i< [value count]; i++) {
            [self recurseValue:[value objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** : 1,4,3,6,5,1,0